# Working in DevC++ but Not working in Visual studio 2017

Tags: c, visual-studio-2017

I have an issue with compiler. My code works in DevC++ but not properly in Visual Studio 2017. In Vs-2017, if I enter only numbers then it will work. but if I enter alphabet, it goes into infinite loop. There is no error in other compiler like DevC++, then why is it not running exactly when i try to compile it in VS-2017.

Here is the full code used in VS-2017 so that you may copy paste to check in VS-2017. Please suggest.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<stdio.h>


int main(void)
{
    int num[10];
    int i;

    printf("Enter 10 numbers: \n\n");

    for (i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
    {
        printf("Number %d =  ", i + 1);

        while (scanf_s("%d", &num[i]) != 1)
        {
           printf("Invalid number. Enter again.\n");

        // fprintf(stderr,"%s\n","Invalid number. Enter again");  // May also use this
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I don't remember any good duplicates (I know there are a few) so I'll give you a hint to the problem instead: When you enter something which is not a number, the function will not extract it from the input buffer. The invalid input will stay in the input buffer *forever* (or until you some other way remove it).

Comment: @ Some programmer dude: I even tried     fflush(stdin) to clear the buffer. But it didnt worked

Comment: @Coolbuddy.: But hey I answerd there...you sgouldn't do that. Don't do `fflush(stdin)` It's Undefined behavior

Comment: Calling `fflush` with an input-only stream (like `stdin`) is actually *undefined behavior, explicitly named as such in the C specification. Some implementations define it as an extension of the language, but you should not really do it anyway. Instead read characters, one by one, in a loop until you have gotten the newline.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude.: Even the question OP linked is a duplicate but the thing is OP commented me earlier that the same code fragment doesn;t work in VStudio...which though OP's posted code doesn't show. Because it won't work anywhere in case of erroneous input

Comment: @coderredoc: Yes I remembered not to use 'fflush'. But I gave a try to check if it runs. If you see the code I posted, it doesnt have 'fflush'.

Comment: @Coolbuddy.: The thing is the way you asked the question is giving wrong impression - if you tried the code I have mentioned it should work but unfortunately you have posted a code which doesn't use anything similar to my code. Then you linked a question. You get what I am saying? Post the code that you have written where you have used my snippet..that will give a proper question.

Comment: Read to a string buffer, then do something like

if(strspn(buffer, "0123456789.,") == strlen(buffer))

Comment: It is weird that `fflush(stdin);` *does not work*. Even if it is undefined per standard, all MSVC versions I could remember (starting with MSVC4) define it as a local extension to clear the input buffer. BTW, the portable way is to read one character at a time until you find a newline or EOF.

Comment: I see your edit but again there is nothing similar to my code. But again you might want to check what @SergeBallesta has said..if `fflush()` works in MSCV4 then you might end up with a different solution where when you get `0` and non-EOF return from `scanf` you will `fflush` the input. I am unaware of MSVC in a detailed manner.

Comment: " if I enter alphabet, it goes into infinite loop. " is the correct functionality. "There is no error in other compiler like DevC++" is the faulty compiler.

Comment: @chux.: OP initially said that he is using the code earlier suggested - but this code is simple plain `scanf` without any flushing of erroneous inputs or anything...

Comment: `(scanf_s("%d", &num[i])` returns either `0,1,EOF`  With `1`, an `int` was successfully read.  With `EOF`, then `stdin` is closed (end-of-file) or rare input error.  With `0`, non-numeric text encountered **and remains** in `stdin`.

Comment: @chux: Thanks for the info. I think I should stop DevC++ for good.

Answer (score 0):

You should input a char (by using the scanf with %c, not %d).
this way your program will expect to look for any char, rather than a digit.
then you should check if it's a digit (0-9) or an alphabet (a-z, A-Z).